# Why there is no current when diode is reverse biased?

Tags: electric-circuits, semiconductor-physics, electronics

If we can see movement of hole as electron electron moving in opposite direction then why there is no current when a diode is reverse biased.

Comment: of course, there is a current, see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shockley_diode_equation

Answer (score 1):

Electrons enters the P-type semiconductor from the battery in the valence band, where there are some available states. But close to the junction, that states are very rare. So few electrons are there to jump to the high energy states of the conduction band of the N-side. Few electrons means very small current. The region is almost an isolant in this direction.

Remember that an electric current consists of electrons pushing the neighbours ahead, that do the same to the next neighbours and so on. If there is a depleted region, the process is stopped.